# PyGame Saving Webcam, the image is split

Tags: python, pygame

I am using pygame to capture an image, and I can't seem to get it right.  Attached is the image, and as you can see the image is split down the middle.

Here is the sourcecode:

```
def getImg(fname):
    pygame.camera.init()
    cm = pygame.camera.list_cameras() 
    cam = pygame.camera.Camera(cm[0])
    cam.start()
    img = cam.get_image()
    pygame.image.save(img,fname)
    cam.stop()
```

[image: Image I have a problem with]

Comment: If I initialize the camera with the application, thus giving it a few seconds to load, the image loads fine, but I dont want to have the camera running the entire time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found a work around that I am posting, since it may be useful in the future:

```
def saveImage(fname):
    pygame.camera.init()
    cam_list = pygame.camera.list_cameras() 
    cam = pygame.camera.Camera(cam_list[0])
    cam.start()
    ## the duplicate get_image():
    ## the first one gets the camera working,
    ## the second captures a clean image
    cam.get_image()
    cam.get_image()
    img = cam.get_image()
    pygame.image.save(img,fname)
    cam.stop()
```